# JQuery selector :visible and .next not working

Tags: jquery, html

When a user clicks the down arrow on the keyboard (keydown event) I am changing the selected list item in the ul by adding .selected to the css class.

The line below can be found in the fiddle under the keydown event. It works fine for numbers, dates but does not identify the last item in the list for characters when they are entered into the textbox.

Steps to reproduce. 1) open fiddle 2) enter any letters 3) try to use the down arrow to get to the "All" li.

```
selected.next(".liSearchType:visible").length == 0
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baileyjames9/kop6rver/2/)

I have been trying to fix this myself but decided someone may have run across this already. All help is appreciated. I've tried changing jquery versions, no love there. I've tried manipulating the order of the li's in the ul, no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.next` only checks the next sibling (not ALL of the next siblings), and so, because you have an invisible `.liSearchType` in between the two visible ones, when it checks the next element, and it filters it by `:visible`, it has a length of 0.

The solution is to use `.nextAll` in combination with `.first`:

http://jsfiddle.net/3mu8cjsa/

```
if (selected.nextAll(".liSearchType:visible").length == 0) {
  selected.siblings(".liSearchType:visible").first().addClass("selected");
} else {
  selected.nextAll(".liSearchType:visible").first().addClass("selected");
}
```